# Error with old key android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I can not publish my old application with an old key that I had created with environment ubuntu 64bit Java 7 and eclipse kepler. I now have Windows x64 , 8 d java eclipse moon but when I choose the old key to sign the application I get an error

> (java.io.EOFException. at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully (unknown Source)

With a new key I make me sign but I need to be signed with this old .

thank you!

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: do you have the old keystore?

Comment: yes, i have the old keystore